# OpenLayers.Format.CQL fails when parsing after/before

Tags: openlayers, cql, geoserver

I am trying to add a filter to my OpenLayers WMS layer

```
var format = new OpenLayers.Format.CQL();

var date = this.controls.UploadAfter.getValue();
    filterArray.push("upload_time after " + date.format("Y-m-d") + "T00:00:00");
```

Then i try to parse it

```
var filter;

try {
  filter = format.read(filterArray.join(" and ")); 
} catch (err) {
   alert("Filter cannot be parsed");
}
```

Error message:

"ERROR: In parsing: [after 2015-05-21T00:00:00], expected one of: ↵    COMPARISON: /^(=|<>|<=|<|>=|>|LIKE)/i↵    BETWEEN: /^BETWEEN/i↵    COMMA: /^,/↵    IS_NULL: /^IS NULL/i"

I guess this text suggest that I cant use the word `after`? I have tested this on my Geoserver and it works when I apply the parameter to the url, like this

```
..&cql_filter=origin_date after 2015-05-13T00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118182/how-to-run-a-temporal-query-on-a-csw-using-geonetwork

use < and > instead. And remember to put ' around the date.